# How to get root as '/' with Kohana3, base_url and mod rewrite

Tags: php, kohana-3

I've only just started using Kohana ( 3 hours ago), and so far it's blown my socks off (and I'm wearing slippers, so that's quite impressive).

Right now, I have a controller 'Controller_FrontPage' with associated views and models and I'm trying to get it accesible from the root of my website (eg, http://www.mysite.com/). If I edit the default controller in the bootstrap from:

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'welcome',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

to `'controller' => '',` I get an error, could not find controller_ (which makes sense), and if I change it to `'controller' => '/',` I get an error, could not find controller_/ (which also makes sense).

If I set `'controller' => 'FrontPage',` everything works fine, but all my links (html::anchor(...)) point to http://www.mysite.com/FrontPage/*.

Is there a way to have all the anchors point to http://www.mysite.com/*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this page in the Unofficial Kohana 3.0 Wiki about Removing the index.php file from the URL:
http://kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php?id=removing_the_index.php

You will also want to learn more about how routes work as the approach you're taking with routes isn't what you want to do.  By changing the route to

```
'controller' => ''
```

or

```
'controller' => '/'
```

you're breaking the route because the route no longer specifies a controller.  Routes are a very powerful part of KO3 and will be a great thing to learn more about.  Take a look at this URL for info about routes - http://kohanaframework.org/guide/tutorials.urls

Let me know if you have follow up questions based on the Unofficial Wiki page.

Bart